# Как вывести метки товара WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Добавил товару метку hit,
в функции добавил

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'my_custom_sale_flash', 10, 3);
    function my_custom_sale_flash($text, $post, $_product) {
    return '<span class="onsale">хит</span>';
  }
     function woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash() {
        wc_get_template( 'loop/sale-flash.php' );
         }
```

добавил sale-flash.php

```
    <?php //if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) : ?>

     <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', '<span class="onsale">' . 
       esc_html__( 'Sale!', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>', $post, $product ); ?>

        <?php // endif;`
```

Теперь все товары с такой меткой, подскажите как это делается?

Comment: а в чем вопрос?

Comment: как вывести стандартно?? просто можете показать как это делаете вы?